# How to find the largest value for a function. What should I do with the natural number if x is not a natural number!

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the largest value of $^{1/} $  if  is a natural number.

My attempt solution is to find the derivative, equate to 0 and solve for that.
However, I get that x is e. Of course e is not a natural number. Hence why I am confused. How should I continue from here?

Should I state that since x is not a natural number the question can't be answered?

Comment: No, because what I am asking is not exactly how to calculate the largest value but how do I interpret "if x is a natural number" when the x is found to be "e". Clearly not a natural number.

Comment: The phrase you are having trouble with asks you to find the largest value of $n^{1/n}$ where $n = 1,2,3,4, \ldots$. This really is a duplicate.

Comment: The method you are applying only works for finding the maximum over an interval of real numbers. It doesn't apply for finding the maximum over the natural numbers, at least not directly.

Comment: Your objection is equivalent to the following:  Whet is the tallest building in Kansas?  Well, the tallest building in the *world* is the Burj Khalifa in Dubai.  But the Burj Khalifa is not in Kansas.  Should I state that since the Burj Khalifa is not in Kansas the question can't be answered?  So $x=e$ is yields the largest value of $f(x)$ but we want the largest value of $f(x)$ that is yielded by a natural number.  Sure $f(x)$ will be *smaller* than $f(e)$ but that doesn't matter.  Of all the natural numbers $n$ which is the largest $f(n)$? That certainly is answerable.

Comment: ... or maybe a better analogy is being asked to find the worlds biggest *dog*.  We find the world's biggest dog.  It's 5ft tall at the shoulder, weighs 250 lbs and stands 7 feet when it stands on it's hind legs.  But then we look at a typical horse.  It's 7 feet tall at the shoulder, ways 1,200 lbs. and stands 12 feet when rearing up.  And it's not even particularly large horse.  So the horse is bigger than the world's largest dog.  Does that mean there is no such thing as the world's largest dog? Because there are animals bigger than the world's largest dog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x) =x^{\frac{1}{x}}$.

If you study the sign of $f'$ you'll see that $f$ is decreasing for $x \geq e$ and increasing for $x \leq e$ .
So if you take $2<e<3$ you have that $f(1)<f(2)$ and $f(n)<f(3)\ \forall n\geq 3$ this means that the maximum is either $2$ or $3$.

But $f(3)=\sqrt[3]{3}>\sqrt{2}=f(2)$ since $9>8$

So the maximum in the naturals must be 3.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

As discussed,

$$\frac{d ~~\text{exp}\left[\frac{\log(x)}{x}\right]}{dx} ~: ~x \geq 3$$

is always negative, specifically because

$$\frac{d \left[\frac{\log(x)}{x}\right]}{dx} = \frac{1 - \log(x)}{x^2} ~: ~x \geq 3$$

is always negative.

Therefore, the problem reduces to manually examining $~\displaystyle n^{(1/n)},~$ for each $~n \in \{1,2,3\}.$

Per the answer of iZxCV, a reasonable shortcut is to realize that for $~1 \leq x \leq e,~$ the pertinent derivative is positive.  Therefore, you can immediately exclude $n=1$ from consideration and simply manually consider $n=2, n=3.$

Further, since $3$ is *closer* to $e = 2.71828...$ than $(2)$, you might **blindly guess** that $~\displaystyle 2^{(1/2)} < 3^{(1/3)}.$

Such a blind guess might be confirmed in one of two ways:

You know from the derivative that $~\displaystyle 3^{(1/3)} > 4^{(1/4)} = 2^{(1/2)}.$

Alternatively, you can reason that

$$2^{(1/2)} = 2^{(3/6)} = 8^{(1/6)} < 9^{(1/6)} = 3^{(2/6)} = 3^{(1/3)}.$$